# How to remove symmetries from this list?

Tags: expression-test, modular-arithmetic, canonicalization

First of all, I work with modular arithmetics and the elements of the arithmetics are lists themselves.

I recognize two kinds of symmetries - shift and mirroring. We could define shift of a list like this:

```
mod = {3, 2};
shiftBy[set_, shift_] := Mod[shift + #, mod] & /@ set
```

I consider two sets to be equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by shifting.

The other symmetry is sign swapping at one or more positions, like swap sign on first member of each element. We could define it like this (return all elements with sign flipped on one of the elements members):

```
mod = {3, 2};
swapSignAt[set_, position_] := Table[
      element[[position]] = Mod[-element[[position]], mod][[position]]; 
      element, 
      {element, set}]
```

## Example

Let's define some sets:

```
set1 = {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}};
set2 = {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};
set3 = {{2, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, 1}};
set4 = {{2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}};
set5 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
listOfSets = {set1,set2,set3,set4,set5}
```

In this case `set1`, `set2`, `set3`, `set4` are considered to be equivalent because `set2 = shiftBy[set1, {2, 1}]`, `set3 = swapSignAt[set1, 1]`, `set4 = swapSignAt[shiftBy[set1, {0, 1}], 1]`.

I need such a function that would remove me the equivalent elements:

```
removeEquivalent[listOfLists]
```

It should return `{set1,set5}` (of course the content not the names like `set1`) or some other set of 2 non-equivalent sets.

How do I construct such a function? I suppose I should create an equivalence test `setsEquivQ` and use `DeleteDuplicates[listOfSets, setsEquivQ]`, but the symmetries are so complicated I have trouble constructing such test.

> Some notes. The value of `mod` can be list of variable length, in the real code `mod` is passed to functions. For example the elements could be triples and `mod` could be `{8,9,7}`. I also have `possibleShifts[mod]` available - it seems that such list might be handy when testing the shifting equivalence.

**Edit:** The element order doesn't matter. We could append `//Sort` to those symmetry functions to make the sets more standartised.

**Edit 2:** For the context. What matters for me in the end is `Differences @* DeleteDuplicates @ Tuples[set, 2]` - differences of all pairs. This result isn't affected by sorting `set` or shifting the elements. And swapping a sign in a component would only swap a sign in result but does not affect the compositions of the result (if 2 of the differences are the same or not same, it will stay that way when sign of one component is flipped on each). However, I am not directly checking the result as some non-equivalent sets can give the same result. [Example](https://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets/show_ds.php?param_id=7).

Comment: Could you define a canonical form such that `set1` and `set2` would be equivalent iff `canonical[set1]==canonical[set2]`?

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks. Nice idea @anderstood, I will have to think about it. But I couldn't come up with a solution within the first 5 minutes :)

Comment: @CarlWoll I edited few mins earlier to include that the order of the elements doesn't matter so there is no "first" element and no clear answer what to shift to 0.

Comment: Never mind my canonicalization comment, then.

Answer (score 3):

The idea, I originally learnt from [Szabolcs's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128216/18767), is to find a canonical form, when possible. Not only is this approach more efficient, I think it is also sounder and helps grasp what is happening.

This is what I suggest in your case to define a canonical form:

1. shift the set using `shiftBy` so that its first element is `{0,0}`
2. take the first list of the set which is not `{0,0}` and apply `swapSignAt` at position $i$ if and only if it decreases the $i$th element.

The following code returns such a canonical form of a set.

```
can[set_] := Block[{},
  (* find the shift position which starts by {0,0} by brute force *)
  set0 = shiftBy[set, mod - set[[1]]];

  (* takes the first non-zero list *)      
  list0 = Select[set0, # != {0, 0} &, 1];

  (* swap pos 1 if  first element of list0 would be reduced *)      
  If[swapSignAt[list0, 1][[1, 1]] < list0[[1, 1]], set0 = swapSignAt[set0, 1]];

  (* swap pos 2 if  second element of list0 would be reduced *)
  If[swapSignAt[list0, 2][[1, 2]] < list0[[1, 2]], set0 = swapSignAt[set0, 2]];

  set0
  ]
```

Then simply use use `DeleteDuplicatesBy`:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[setlist, can]
(* {{{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}} *)
```

which returns `set1` and `set5`, as expected.

**Note** The above takes into account the order of the set. If you want to relax this constraint, you should sort the elements of the set (I have not tried; maybe it is more complicated than it seems...).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! As the ordering doesn't matter, this is a bit harder as it's unclear which element should be shifted to 0. I might make a `can[set_,n_]` that would make canonical form with respect to nth element not the first one. Then I can compare `can[set1,1]//Sort` with each of `can[set2,n]//Sort`. Let me know if you have an even better idea :)

Comment: @Džuris The order of the lists (e.g. `{1,0}`) do not matter, but does the order within the list matter (is `{1,0}` and `{0,1}` similar?) ?

Comment: @Džuris Does `can /@ Sort @ setlist` do what you want?

Comment: yes, `{1,0}` and `{0,1}` are different elements. You can reorder elements or shift all of the elements in set, but you can't tinker with individual elements. And I am not sure if you wrote what you meant in the last comment... ? But if you'd sort and then canonize the sets, `set1` and `set4` would end up different, but they are equivalent.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to find a canonical form in this case. Is efficiency a concern for you? Otherwise you could always do a brute-force approach...

Comment: a `set` has `2^Length[set]` possible sign flippings. It means that brute-forcing would require exponentially growing amount of calculations. If possible, I'd like to avoid that.