# Cyclically Flat Functions

Tags: function-construction, order

Any idea how to define some operator ° such that e.g. $((a°b)°c)°d=a°(b°(c°d))=a°b°c°d=b°c°d°a$ (but $a°b\neq{b°a}$ in general)? So ° is Flat plus (insert here)?

Comment: If I define $e=b \circ c \circ d$ then you propose $a \circ e \neq e \circ a$, but on the other hand you say $a \circ (b \circ c \circ d) = a \circ b \circ c \circ d = b \circ c \circ d \circ a = (b \circ c \circ d) \circ a = e \circ a$. If $\circ$ is flat and cyclic then **mustn't** $a \circ e = e \circ a$...?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I think that a non-commutative "operator" with the requested properties could be `Tr[A.B.C]` where the arguments are matrices.  This is only defined for matrices whose sizes agree.  With two arguments it is commutative, but with three or more, generally not.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed a tensor trace in "reality".

Comment: Somewhat related: [(17041)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041/121), [(55702)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55702/121)

Comment: Tensor trace cannot be `Flat`. Just try to imagine `Tr[a,Tr[b,c]] == Tr[a,b,c]`. To define tensor trace fully consistent you will need two functions, say, `tr` and `dot`, where `dot` is `Flat` and `tr[dot[x__]]` is cyclic. How to implement such functions depends on what kind of patterns do you want to use. If you want to combine `tr` and `dot` in one symbol, you should not expect it to be `Flat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated to fix cyclic sort, and to allow additional operator definitions**

@mikado mentions that giving an operator the `Flat` attribute in addition to a cyclic automatic sort makes the operator commutative. This is because the cyclic automatic sort gets applied during the `Flat` pattern matching rewrite. It is possible to avoid this issue as follows:

```
ClearAll[SmallCircle];
SetAttributes[SmallCircle,Flat];

u_SmallCircle:= Module[{args = Hold @@ Unevaluated @ u, ord},
    ord = First @ Ordering @ NestList[RotateLeft, args, Length[args] - 1];
    RotateLeft[Unevaluated[u], ord-1] /; ord != 1
]
```

The key is that `SmallCircle[u__]` is never used, and so [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) pattern matching rewrites of the sort:

```
SmallCircle[a, b, c] -> SmallCircle[SmallCircle[a, b], c]
```

never occur. Simple example:

```
a ∘ c ∘ b
e ∘ c ∘ b
```

> a∘c∘b
>
> b∘e∘c

**Update**

The OP requested to have support for additional [`SmallCircle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmallCircle) definitions. The problem with adding additional [`SmallCircle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmallCircle) rules is that inevitably these additional rules will cause the operator to become commutative. One can either use mikado's approach, or one can add a helper function to take care of these additional rules. For example:

```
ClearAll[SmallCircle, iSmallCircle];
SetAttributes[{SmallCircle, iSmallCircle}, Flat];

u_SmallCircle := Module[{args = Hold @@ Unevaluated @ u, r},
    r = cycleSort[iSmallCircle @@ args];
    SmallCircle @@ r /; r =!= args
]

iSmallCircle[b, a] := d
iSmallCircle[a, x___, b] := iSmallCircle[d, x]

cycleSort[u_iSmallCircle] := RotateLeft[
    Hold @@ u,
    First @ Ordering @ NestList[RotateLeft, u, Length[u] - 1] - 1
]
```

A couple examples:

```
e ∘ b ∘ a ∘ x ∘ b ∘ a
a ∘ c ∘ b
```

> d∘e∘d∘x
>
> c∘d

Comment: Now suppose that in your example I have an additional simplification rule, say b°a=d. Under which condition will Mathematica "find" it, i.e. try out a°c°b=b°a°c and then simplify to d°c? (And not being stuck at the canonical order a°c°b)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann See edit

Comment: It's tricky. :-) (I also already thought about if the pattern a(...)b would be sufficient to take care of a b°a in the "wrong" place.) THX.

Answer (score 3):

The following definitions give what you request.   I use a definition of `can1` (from [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128216/36788)) to canonicalise the order of the arguments.

```
SmallCircle[a___, SmallCircle[b___], c___] := SmallCircle[a, b, c]
can1 = RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] &;
SmallCircle[u__] /; First[Ordering[{u}, 1]] != 1 := SmallCircle @@ can1[{u}]
```

This gives

```
{((a∘b)∘c)∘d, b∘c∘d∘a, a∘c∘b∘d}
(* {a∘b∘c∘d, a∘b∘c∘d, a∘c∘b∘d} *)
```

Note that we can't use `SetAttribute` `Flat` as this effectively makes the operator commutative (it lets Mathematica permute any subsequence)

Comment: `Flat` does not make the operator commutative. Maybe you're thinking of `Orderless`?

Comment: @CarlWoll quite correct.  However, if I give `SmallCircle` the attribute `Flat` (in conjunction with the 2nd definition) it becomes commutative (try it if you don't believe me).  For this reason, I have to give a slightly weaker version of flattening in the 1st definition.

Comment: I see. That's because you use SmallCircle[u__] .. in your definition. I'll give an alternate answer that doesn't suffer from this issue.